# xdist showing error while passing object as paramaeter in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, xdist

```
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\users\harshil.gajera\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\users\harshil.gajera\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\users\harshil.gajera\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\users\harshil.gajera\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\xdist\dsession.py", line 112, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     self.loop_once()
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\users\harshil.gajera\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\xdist\dsession.py", line 135, in loop_once
INTERNALERROR>     call(**kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "c:\users\harshil.gajera\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\xdist\dsession.py", line 177, in worker_workerfinished
INTERNALERROR>     assert not crashitem, (crashitem, node)
INTERNALERROR> AssertionError: ('tests/test_my_addon.py::Test_App::test_props_fields_positive[notvalid::field::extractone]', <WorkerController gw0>)
INTERNALERROR> assert not 'tests/test_my_addon.py::Test_App::test_props_fields_positive[notvalid::field::extractone]'
```

Comment: This error is happening in your test `test_props_fields_positive` - could you edit your post to include this test?

Comment: Please post a complete error log. If it is possible, also add a [mcve].